# Find the SVM kernel in detecting if a substring in a given string

Tags: machine-learning, svm, kernelization

Consider the task of learning to find a sequence of characters ("signature") in a file that indicates whether it contains a virus or not and let $\mathcal{X}$ be the set of all finite strings over some alphabet set $\Sigma$, and let $\mathcal{X}_d$ be the set of all such strings of length at most $d$. The learning hypothesis class is $\mathcal{H}=\lbrace h_v: v\in\mathcal{X}_d\rbrace$, where, for a string $x\in\mathcal{X}$, $h_v(x)$ is $1$ iff $v$ is a substring of $x$ (and $h_v(x) = −1$ otherwise).

Let $s = |\mathcal{X}_d|$ and consider a mapping $\psi$ to a space $\mathbb{R}^s$, so that each coordinate of $\psi (x)$ corresponds to some string $v$ and indicates whether $v$ is a substring of $x$ (that is, for every $x \in \mathcal{X}, \psi(x)$ is a vector in $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace^{|\mathcal{X}_d|}$). Note that the dimension of this feature space is exponential in $d$.

Given that information, I need to show that every member of the class $\mathcal{H}$ can be realized by composing a linear classifier over $\psi (x)$, and, moreover, by such a halfspace whose norm is 1 and that attains a margin of 1.

However, I was confused over the $v$ in the definition of $\mathcal{H}=\lbrace h_v: v\in\mathcal{X}_d\rbrace$. My understanding is that this $v$ denotes any string $v\in\mathcal{X}_d$ not just some fixed string. Suppose my understanding is correct then denote by $v_1, v_2,..., v_s$ all strings in $\mathcal{X}_d$ and then we can define $\psi$ by

$$
\psi(x) =
\begin{bmatrix}
h_{v_1}(x) \\
h_{v_s}(x) \\
\vdots \\
h_{v_s}(x)
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Thus we have $h_{v_i}(x)=\psi (x)_i$ (the i(th)-element of $\psi (x)$). But I don't see any the linear classifiers in this equation let alone the margin and the norm constraints?

Comment: "Let $s = |\mathcal{X}_d|$ and consider a mapping to a space $R^s$." what $R$ refer to? Do you mean $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Reading the first part also lead to some confusion. The way I understand your problem an to connect with having a virus or not makes me see $\mathcal{X}_d$ as the set of viruses (strings) of length at most $d$, where $d$ is the maximal length a virus can take.

Comment: Do you have this problem in some resources so that I can understand it? It's sp confusing the way you posed the problem.

Comment: @Ayoubayjx, that's a typo, yes $\mathbb{R}$ is correct. Based on the paragraph, I can see that the $\mathcal{X}_d$ is some restricted domain space (that is it contains all strings of length $\le d$), in which some strings contain virus (i.e. those who contain a sequence characterizes the virus), but some do not.

Comment: You can find it [here](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf), in section **16.2.1** Kernels as a Way to Express Prior Knowledge.